# fix importing errors in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, python-3.x, pydev

I have a folder structure:

```
/mama-mia
    /framework
        /classses
            FrameworkClass1.py - contains FrameworkClass1
    /projects
        /project1
            Project1Class.py - contains Project1Class
```

inside `Project1Class.py`

```
from framework.classses import FrameworkClass1
```

Eclipse shows error in this line "Unresolved inmport". How to fix this error - in Eclipse only. For runtime it is worknig as paths are added dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the /framework parent folder as a source folder (i.e.: that's the folder that's added to the PYTHONPATH).

See: http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_project_conf2.html for more details.

Comment: I've already tried to add `/$(PROJECT_DIR_NAME)/mama-mia` and `/$(PROJECT_DIR_NAME)/mama-mia\framework` to 'project properties/PyDev - PYTHONPATH/source folders' and it did not help.

Comment: I've created new project exactly with those files and it works. Strange.

Comment: Make sure you **don't** add /$(PROJECT_DIR_NAME)/mama-mia\framework to the PYTHONPATH (only its parent folder).